# Nginx on Kubernetes (99: Cannot assign requested address)

Tags: linux, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy

So I have a service of my application and want nginx to proxy the connection to it. I used IP address to tell the nginx which is the Service Node port of the application (100.68.202.75). The issue is that when the pods starts it gives me:

2019/05/25 17:32:38 [emerg] 1#1: bind() to 100.71.178.70:443 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 100.71.178.70:443 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)

Application runs separately on a different deployment with a service. I just want to tell to listen for  that service. So it can redirect the traffic.

```
upstream so5098.exampler.com {
                server  100.68.202.75:8080;
               } 
   server {
        listen      80;
        server_name so5098.exampler.com masterqa-okta.exampler.com masterqapayrolltestingping.exampler.com;
        rewrite     ^(.*)   https://$host$1 permanent;
    }
        server {

        listen                  100.68.202.75:443;
        ssl                     on;
        ssl_certificate         /home/xenon/.ssl/exampler.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /home/xenon/.ssl/exampler.com.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:AES256-SHA256:AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH:!aNULL';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        server_name masterqa.exampler.com masterqa-okta.exampler.com masterqapayrolltestingping.exampler.com;
        # Upload file size limit
        client_max_body_size    50m;
        # bypass tomcat for profile images
        location ~* /masterqa/profile/[0-9]*/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
            root /opt/documents/so5098/;
            rewrite /opt/documents/saintssecurity/docs/([0-9]*)/(.*) /$1/$2 break;
        }
    # bypass tomcat for company logos
        location ~* /so5098/logo/[0-9]*/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
                root /opt/example/docs-branch/;
                rewrite /so5098/logo/([0-9]*)/(.*) /$1/$2 break;
        }
        # bypass tomcat for company theme
        location ~* /masterqa/companyTheme/theme/[0-9]+_.*\.css$ {
                root /opt/documents/so5098;
                rewrite /masterqa/companyTheme/theme/([0-9]*)_.*.css /$1/$1.css break;
        }

        location /so5098 {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass http://100.68.202.75:8080/so5098;
            proxy_redirect http://$host https://$host;
        }
        location /so5098/api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/masterqa/api;
                }
        location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://100.68.202.75:8080/so5098;
                }
        }
```

Comment: You wouldn’t generally hardwire the ip like that because pod ips are randomly assigned.

Comment: It is the IP of the service. How do u suggest to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `listen 100.68.202.75:443;` with `listen 443 ssl;`. Pod IP is dynamic and changes every time it gets restarted.

Comment: Ok and for proxy pass which address should I use to pass to the pod

Comment: if your application runs in the same Kubernetes cluster then you'd better put there service name instead of service IP. That is more Kubernetes way.